# How to set up Admob interstitials on Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows, admob

hi guys please i need to set up Admob interstitial on my windows 8 app, i have succesfully set up banners, but since downloads are not much i want to increase my earning by displaying interstitial instead. So please give my step by step guide and a sample code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code

```
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
void admobinterstitial()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("YOUR AD UNIT ID");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

        interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
        interstitialAd.FailedToReceiveAd += interstitialAd_FailedToReceiveAd;
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
    }

    void interstitialAd_FailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        interstitial = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Interstitial failed");
    }

    private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {
        interstitial = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Interstitial received");
    }
```